# CSS 1px height issue firefox versus webkit browsers/ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I have an issue that seems to be common, but can be caused via various ways.

On my project's website ( **FIXED** ) adding products to the dock in the left and changing the quantity does not cause issues. However when I open my project in a non mozilla browser the `<p class="count">` element (product quantity) causes me headaches. It's **one pixel too low** and I cannot seem to resolve this..

Ofcourse an ugly hack is possible with jquery, but I know this is likely caused by inproper clearing floats or line-height, I hope someone can shed some light on this, it's been bugging me for hours.

---

The ugly solution (needs to be fit with ajax still)..

```
<script>
$(document).ready (
function() {
  if (!$.browser.mozilla) {
   $('#test .count').css('padding-bottom','1px');
  }
}
);
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps play around the line-height of .count. Also, off topic, but I'd change the wording of the dock because it says to drag items, and I did, which didn't work, when actually I should've just been clicking on the plus icons.

Comment: dragging is yet to be implemented ;) thanks

Comment: line-height issue with the element / document reset

Comment: So does that mean my suggestion was correct?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced something similar with FireFox and images. The trick was to set the div or in my case image to

```
display:inline;
```

by default images are set to

```
display:block;
```

which caused an extra pixel at the bottom of the image to bloat the surrounding div.